# Vue history mode and express server getting 404 error

Tags: express, vue.js

I'm running a vue SPA in a express server. The problem is when an use history mode and I refresh the page I get a 404 not found exception.
I tried to use `connect-history-api-fallback` but is not working.

My express configuration looks like this:

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');


var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(history())
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 6):

You trying to use history mode of router with wrong express server script.
For getting things working, you may use my script. 
Here is the my server.js for running Vue app with history mode.
server.js (with Express):

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

const app = express();

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("App now running on port", port);
});
```

Place this file in the root directory of your project (not src).

Run this script with Node: `node server.js`

Don't forget build your app for production ;)!

Answer (score 2):

Actually,You can refer to this middleware [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) to fix this problem.